# Making hover color stay if link is active

Tags: php, html, css, hover

I'm working on a website using PHP, HTML and CSS. Currently in my navigation bar, I've set the background color to be grey. When the user hovers over the navigation bar, each link gets a blue background, however when I click the link, the background color goes back to grey. How do I make the hover color blue stay if that particular link is active.

This is the code for my navigation bar.

```
<tr>
<td width="800" height="54">
<div id="nav" >
<ax><b><font face="Arial" ><a style="text-decoration: none; color:#303030" href="index.php" >HOME</a></font></b></ax>
<bx><b><font face="arial" ><a style="text-decoration: none; color:#303030" href="edituser.php?own=y">IT</a></font></b></bx>
<cx><b><font face="arial" ><a style="text-decoration: none; color:#303030" href="newsevents.php">HUMAN RESOURCE</a></font></b></cx>
<dx><b><font face="arial" ><a style="text-decoration: none; color:#303030" href="industries.php">PROCUREMENT</a></font></b></dx>
<ex><b><font face="arial" size="1"><a style="text-decoration: none; color:#303030" href="http://www.csmphilippines.com/aboutus.html">FINANCE</a></font></b></ex>
<fx><b><font face="arial" ><a style="text-decoration: none; color:#303030" href="hact.php">HACT</a></font></b></fx>
</div>
</td>
```

This is the code for my CSS

```
#nav {
text-decoration:none;
padding-bottom:10px;
border-bottom:none;
width:
}

#nav ax {
display:inline;
padding:15px;
padding-left:31px;
padding-right:28px;
background-color:#ececec;
text-decoration:none;
}

#nav bx {
display:inline;
padding:15px;
padding-left:45px;
padding-right:45px;
background-color:#ececec;
text-decoration:none;
}

#nav cx {
display:inline;
padding:15px;
padding-left:45px;
padding-right:45px;
background-color:#ececec;
text-decoration:none;
}

#nav dx {
display:inline;
padding:15px;
padding-left:45px;
padding-right:45px;
background-color:#ececec;
text-decoration:none;
}

#nav ex {
display:inline;
padding:15px;
padding-left:53px;
padding-right:53px;
background-color:#ececec;
text-decoration:none;
}

#nav fx {
display:inline;
padding:15px;
padding-left:30px;
padding-right:30px;
background-color:#ececec;
text-decoration:none;
}

#nav ax:hover {
background-image:url(images/tabbackit.jpg); 
background-repeat:repeat-x;
height:900px;
}


#nav bx:hover {
background-image:url(images/tabbackit.jpg); 
background-repeat:repeat-x;
height:900px;
}
#nav cx:hover {
background-image:url(images/tabback.jpg); 
background-repeat:repeat-x;
height:900px;
}

#nav dx:hover {
background-image:url(images/tabbackproc.jpg); 
background-repeat:repeat-x;
height:900px;
}
#nav ex:hover {
background-image:url(images/tabbackfin.jpg); 
background-repeat:repeat-x;
height:900px;
}

#nav fx:hover {
background-image:url(images/tabbackhact.jpg); 
background-repeat:repeat-x;
height:900px;
}
```

Comment: Is the user taken to a new page when links are clicked, or is data loaded in dynamically?

Comment: If im correct, it goes to a new page. For example, when the user clicks on Home, hes taken to index.php

Comment: And when they're on index.php, you want the home link to be styled differently?

Comment: not differently but i want the hover style to remain constant until index.php is active

Comment: What do you mean by "Until index.php is active" ?

Comment: Do you want different links to be highlighted in different pages as @Jonathan said, or just the hover colour to remain when the user clicks on a link, which is what is referred to as the `:active` state?

Comment: so if the user is on the home page (index.php) the home button in the navigation bar will have the same image as what I set for hover. Lets say I want to go to the IT page, so when i hover over its gonna be that background i specified for its hover, but when i actually CLICK it, and stay on that page, the hover background should remain as that image.

Comment: @AbhranilDas the hover colour/image to stay active when the user is on that page, Yes. However I even tried the :active but it doesn't work

Comment: @AbhranilDas Additionally, the :active is only true from the point the user clicks on the link, until he releases the click. So thats not exactly what im looking for

Comment: Right, it won't, because `:active` is not meant for that. Basically you're looking for different styles in each page.

Comment: @Coozekz   you can give (.active) class to the particular tag which you want to be highlighted...

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is to give each page its own id in the body tag:

```
<body id="pgAbout">
```

Then have a seperate id for each menu item:

```
<li id="mnuAbout">
```

Using CSS you can style the link now for the page you're on:

```
#pgAbout #mnuAbout,
#pgOther #mnuOther
{
   /* Styles here */
}
```

[Here's a brief demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mFNHy/)

**Update**

[Here's another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nqzNm/) using your own HTML to clarify how it works a bit.

Comment: Can I use class="Home" instead of Id? I tried that but it still doesn't work

Comment: You can use class if you like. What exactly did you try?

Comment: I've added a demo link to my answer for you @Coozekz

Comment: <ax><b><font face="Arial" ><a class="Home" style="text-decoration: none; color:#303030" href="index.php" >HOME</a></font></b></ax>

Comment: then in css, I wrote.. #nav .Home ax{ ... }  but it doesnt work

Comment: `Home` doesn't contain an `ax` tag. The `ax` tag contains `Home` (it's the other way round). Remove the ax bit from your code and it might work. See my example.

Comment: Theres gonna be a problem if i remove the ax, bx, cx.. etc tags. If you notice in the css, each hover for the tag has a different background image, hence i put those tags the first place. Is there a way to do this with the tags?

Comment: You need to remove it from your CSS for this specific piece, not from the HTML or anyhting else.

Comment: I've created another example using your own markup. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/nqzNm/

Comment: so for each page, in css i type .pg(name) .(name) ?

Comment: Yeah. It's just one block of CSS, a class for the body tag and a class for each menu item. Job done :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple thing you could do is use the same stylesheet for all your pages, but use different CSS classes to highlight the corresponding link on each page. For example, on index.php, use the `.active` class to highlight the Home link.

Since you're new (as you said), let's break it down:

Use the same CSS for all the pages. However, define two CSS classes for the navbar elements: one is the `.regular` state, the other is the `.active` state. In every page, give the link corresponding to that page the active class, while the other links remain in the regular class.

But then, would you want it to *remain* a link?

Comment: Im not sure haha, still new to PHP and CSS. I just thought if theres a way to make the hover color/background to stay if the user IS on that particular link, after he clicks one of those buttons in the navigation bar

Comment: I understand your question. I'll just elucidate the answer a bit more for you then.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, Just put following code
For example,
On Home page, put following code in HEAD

```
<style type="text/css">
    #nav ax{
        background-image:url(images/tabbackit.jpg); 
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: so I put this inside the PHP file? But the initial style I have set is this... <a style="text-decoration: none; color:#303030"

Comment: oh wait disregard my comment, I just understood what you said. Ill try it out, sec

Comment: You do realise this is just a less managable version of my code?

Comment: I tried out his version before I could do yours, but thanks a million for helping :D